# SideMenu layout example react-native-navigation v2

Tags: react-native-navigation

I need an example with sideMenu react-native-navigation v2. Ideally, I want to navigate from side menu component to other screens (e.g stack with bottom tabs, accounts screen, FAQs screen)

currently this is my layout

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    sideMenu: {
      left: {
        component: {
          name: 'screen.SideMenu',
        }
      },
      center: {
        bottomTabs: {
          id: 'tabs',
          options: {
            topbar: {
              visible: true,
            }
          },
          children: [
            {
              stack: {
                id: 'tab1',
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'screen.Home',
                      options: {
                        topbar: {
                          visible: true
                        },
                        bottomTab: {
                          fontSize: 12,
                          text: 'Home',
                          icon: homeIcon,
                          textColor: theme.$tabColor,
                          selectedTextColor: '#000',
                          selectedIconColor: '#000',
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              stack: {
                id: 'tab2',
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'screen.Events',
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          text: 'Events',
                          fontSize: 12,
                          icon: eventsIcon,
                          textColor: theme.$tabColor,
                          selectedTextColor: '#000',
                          selectedIconColor: '#000',
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                ]
              }
            },
          ],
        },
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In my Side Menu component I am calling this function.

```
goToAccountsScreen = () => {
   console.log(this.props.componentId)
  Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
     component: {
         name: 'screen.Accounts',
     }
   })
}
```

how do I add the Accounts screen to my layout

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Try This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944506/wix-react-native-navigation-v2-how-to-push-new-screen-to-current-screen-from-s?rq=1